# Spring RestController only considers the first media type and ignores the rest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mime-types, spring-restcontroller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "text/plain", "application/json" })
```

If I send a request:

```
curl --header "Accept: text/plain, application/json" "http://localhost:8229/test/test"
```

It sends back a 406 Unacceptable response with HTML response body. Expected Response is a JSON object with 200 OK.

But if I reverse the order of mime-types:

```
curl --header "Accept: application/json, text/plain" "http://localhost:8229/test/test"
```

Then it sends the expected response (in JSON).

Is this expected behavior? Why is it ignoring the second media type?

**PS**: I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.5 release

**Edit**: I get the same error if I send `"Accept: */*"`. That API can return JSON or text/plain depending upon an internal condition.

Comment: Because that is how content negotiation works. It works from most desired to lesser desired ones. In your first request you apparently prefer text over JSON. But I suspect you haven't configured anything ont he server side to return plain text.

Comment: Do I need to configure something specially? I thought spring will check if the most desired mime-type is not being returned, the lesser desired will be checked (if that is the one being returned), and then return that.

I had also tried "Accept: */*", I got the same error with this.

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's because of not configuring your web config component in server side. Refer to [Content Negotiation](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc)  to configure it.

Comment: I see there are configuration in xml and java methods. But don't see any Annotation based configuration. Are you aware of any annotations that would do the job?

Comment: there are both xml and java class based configuration in that topic. there is no specific annotation, just use java configuration rather than xml. use ContentNegotiationConfigurer  class to configure mediaType and so on.